# Reactjs and Mongodb connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have a fundamental question about Reactjs and Mongodb. I want to build a react app which has a "search" feature that shows results from the database. However, I have an issue on understanding how to implement the connection between the react app and the database.

Sorry for the general question. Every help or hint on how to proceed will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you noted, your question is too broad and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow. For what it's worth: AFAIK the most common way to do this is to have a Node.js/Express server backend that connects to the Mongo and provides an API endpoint for the React application that runs on the client side and uses the endpoint to fetch data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is completely back-end agnostic. Which means you would have to implement the connection yourself.

The regular way is, you setup MongoDB and a Node.js server (or whatever back-end you like) then you connect the Node.js server to MongoDB (via MongoDBs JavaScript SDK) and your React client, which runs in the browser to your Node.js server (via HTTP, express framework could help here).

Browser -> Node.js -> MongoDB.

But MongoDB also has a REST interface you could use directly via the browser, like it's mentioned in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277603/1016383

Would probably be okay for small proof of concepts or experiements,.