# can i use reactjs and mongodb without MERN Stack

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

i'm looking creating a reacrjs  web-app connectting to mongodb database directly !!
withe out using "MERN STACK" or "express" or "nodejs"

Comment: You need a server to connect to Database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276557/using-mongodb-from-client-with-javascript/16277603#16277603

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting to a database (including MongoDB) from a web app is dangerous. Web applications send all their code to the user's browser when they visit the website. A user can right click on a page and click 'view page source' to see all the code. A user can also see the code in chrome developer tools. They can see any username, passwords, or urls you might use to connect. They can see all the queries that are sent and figure out how your data is structured. It becomes very easy for a hacker to find weak spots in your code and steal data or take over the website. ReactJS has a chrome browser extension which tells you if a website is using React. If it is, the extension will show you the code in the React tab of chrome developers tools.

If you are building a ReactJS web app then you are already using NodeJS. ReactJS web apps are NodeJS apps with some imported ReactJS libraries.

Comment: thanks for answer Mr: Raymound  me what about using **PHP** as _back-end_ and **react-js** as a _front-end_ is that possible  !!

Comment: You can use php in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you cannot connect to MongoDB directly from “React” without creating a backend server. React is a front-end framework that is used to build user interfaces. It does not have the ability to connect to databases or perform CRUD operations on its own.
To connect to MongoDB from React, you will need to create a server (say Node.js server) that will act as an intermediary between React and MongoDB.
However, you can consider Next.js as a React framework that includes a built-in server that can be used to connect to MongoDB. This means that you don’t need to create a separate Node.js server for your application.