# trying to implement a search on mongoDB and get the results to display on page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, search

[search function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqezA.png)[displays the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MtWO.png)[implements the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Lxy.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: yes I am sorry. the input form wasn't accepting my codes. tried formatting everyway I could and still got errors.

Comment: if there is an easier way I would love to know

Answer (score 1):

React is completely back-end agnostic. This means you would have to implement the connection yourself.

The regular way is, you setup MongoDB and a Node.js server (or whatever back-end you like) then you connect the Node.js server to MongoDB (via MongoDBs JavaScript SDK) and your React client, which runs in the browser to your Node.js server (via HTTP, express framework could help here).

Browser -> Node.js -> MongoDB.

But MongoDB also has a REST interface you could use directly via the browser, like it's mentioned in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277603/1016383

Would probably be okay for small proof of concepts or experiements,.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. I have done all the backend. the node server and mongo and using pusher as the middleware.

Comment: @alexanderuk if you find this answer useful please mark is as accepted